# How do I get a label's text with their classname in a loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have many labels with the same classname, but they all have different text. I want to loop through them and get this text.

Here is what I have:

```
<label class="mylabel pull-left"> Hello </label>
<label class="mylabel pull-left"> olleH </label>
.....
```

I try this:

```
<script>
    var element = document.getElementsByClassName('mylabel');
    for(var i = 0; i<element.length;i++) {
         alert(element[i].text());
    }
</script>
```

But I get this error:

```
TypeError: element[i].text is not a function
```

I tried `alert(element[i].text)` but that just returns `undefined`.

But I can get its className with `alert(element[i].className)`, so why can't I get its text?

Comment: Where's your **jQuery**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The is no `text` function in javascript. Try to use `innerHTML` instead:

```
var element = document.getElementsByClassName('mylabel');
for(var i = 0; i<element.length;i++) {
     alert(element[i].innerHTML);
}
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/28sd9/)**

if you use jQuery, you can use **[text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)** like what you're trying:

```
$.each($('.mylabel'), function() {
    alert($(this).text());
})
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/28sd9/1/)**

Comment: Using the above JS code how can I get only the text of the checked inputs?

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
$('.mylabel').each(function() {
    var x = $(this).text();
    alert(x);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Question:** But I can get its className with alert(element[i].className), so why can't I get its text?

**Answer:** You aren't targetting a `javascript` element anymore, just a reference to it. You need to use `jQuery` for this function if you want to get further `innerHTML` information.

Update your use-case with a `jQuery selector $`.

#### Fiddle Here: http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/ZKzVz/

```
<label class="mylabel pull-left"> Hello </label>
<label class="mylabel pull-left"> olleH </label>

var element = $('.mylabel');
for(var i = 0; i<element.length;i++) {
     alert($(element[i]).text());
}
```

Furthermore, you could shorten even further like so:

```
$('.mylabel').each(function() {
    alert($(this).text());
});
```